# Add class to current open infowindow

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with a bunch of markers on it. I also have a corresponding sidebar that lists those markers. When you click one of them, its corresponding marker on the map opens the info window. This works perfectly.

When you click one of these links in the sidebar I want to add a class of 'bounce' to it so it becomes visibly the active/open link. Likewise if I click a marker on the map I want the same class to get added to the list item. When another marker or link is clicked I'd like that class to be moved the most current clicked item.

I have a jsFiddle of my map code here: http://jsfiddle.net/3xkuybrf/2/

All my code does below is add a class to the first clicked link and doesn't do what I want. I want to add a class to the active/open link/marker and when another link/marker is clicked I want the class to be removed and added to the newest clicked item:

```
$(document).on('click', '#p'+index, function(){
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

        if ($('#listdata li').hasClass('bounce')) {
            $(this).removeClass( "bounce" ); 
        } else {
            $(this).addClass( "bounce" );
        }

    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/3xkuybrf/6/

Replace the following lines:

```
if ($('#listdata li').hasClass('bounce')) {
    $(this).removeClass( "bounce" ); 
} else {
    $(this).addClass( "bounce" );
}
```

with the below line:

```
$('#p'+index).addClass('bounce').siblings().removeClass('bounce');
```

The above line of code adds the class when you click on the div and the below code adds the class to the related div when you clcik on the marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   $('#p'+index).addClass('bounce').siblings().removeClass('bounce');
   infowindow.open( map, marker );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `if` statement with the following 2 lines:

```
$('#listdata div').removeClass("bounce");
$(this).addClass("bounce");
```

What this does: remove the bounce class to all `#listdata div` and add it to the current element.